# how to apply same function to multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am applying the same function to multiple dataframes. For example, I want to merge the column2 and column3 in df1. After applying this function, the df1 will get a new column called col2_col3.

```
 df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(3, 5), y = seq(1, 5, 1), ID = letters[1:5])
 df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(5, 5), y = seq(2, 6, 1), ID = letters[6:10])
#I define a function:
PasteTwoColumn <- function(x) 
{
  x$col2_col3 <- paste(x[,2], x[,3], sep = "_")
  return(x)
}
#apply the function to the df1, it works.
df1 <- PasteTwoColumn(df1)
# but I failed by an lappy function, because it returns a list, not the dataframe
mylist <- list(df1, df2) 
result <- lapply(mylist, PasteTwoColumn)
```

I want to continue to apply this function to all my dataframes, eg. df1, df2, df3 ...df100. The output file should keep the same type of dataframe and the name.  
 
 The **lapply** function does not work, because it returns a list, not the separate data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can keep the datasets in a `list` and loop over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(df1, df2), PasteTwoColumn)
```

---

If there are many datasets, use `mget` to get the values of the datasets into a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:100)), PasteTwoColumn)
```

Or instead of `paste`, we can also use `ls`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')), PasteTwoColumn)
```

If we need to update the original object, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv) #not recommended though
```

---

If we need to use a `for` loop

```
for(obj in paste0("df", 1:100)) {
      assign(obj,  PasteTwoColumn(get(obj)))
  }
```

Comment: The last one [for loop] is exactly what I want. thanks for showing me in many ways. I learn a lot.